How to Build a Chart with Multiple Data Series
I need to build a chart with multiple data series to compare results for each animal (e.g., "horse old" vs "horse new") according to specific elements (e.g., P3, M1, M2, and MC). I want to visualize this data in a single chart that is clear and easy to understand. Could you advise on the best type of chart to use and how to represent the data effectively? I am working with Excel and R.




Horse old
Mule old
Donkey old
All old
Horse new
Mule new
Donkey new
All new




P3
98.6
100

98.8
100
100

100


M1
80
100

80
100
100

100


M2
95
62.5

90.5
100
81.3

97.4


MC
87.7
100
0
88.4
97.5
100
100
97.9




Reshape your data to long format, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/680068, then use ggplot lineplot with grouping https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-several-groups-ggplot2.html

Do a chart with the first data series and sort titles etc. Then add each series and format the detail, Excel charts allow many series.

as zx8754 already mentioned, you can use the melt function to elongate the data table. Then we can add the categories (old and new) and specific elements, group and plot. Please add some data for the poor donkey, otherwise the result will look weird!
install.packages("reshape2", "tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

# Original Data
data <- data.frame(
  Horse_old = c(98.6, 80.0, 95.0, 87.7),
  Mule_old = c(100.0, 100.0, 62.5, 100.0),
  Donkey_old = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.0), # give values for donkey!
  All_old = c(98.8, 80.0, 90.5, 88.4),
  Horse_new = c(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 97.5),
  Mule_new = c(100.0, 100.0, 81.3, 100.0),
  Donkey_new = c(100.0, 100.0, NA, 100.0), # give values for donkey!
  All_new = c(100.0, 100.0, 97.4, 97.9)
)

# Reshape data for plotting
data_long <- melt(data, 
                  variable.name = "Category", 
                  value.name = "Value") 

# Extract type (old/new) and animal from 'Category'
data_long <- data_long %>%
  mutate(
    Animal = gsub("_old|_new", "", Category),
    Group = ifelse(grepl("old", Category), "Old", "New"),
    Type = rep(c("P3", "M1", "M2", "MC"), times = 8) # Repeated for clarity
  )

# Plot the data
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Type, y = Value, color = Animal, group = interaction(Animal, Group))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group), size = 1.2, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "white") + # Adds points with clear centers
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) + # Differentiate old vs new
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") + # Add a distinguishable color palette
  facet_wrap(~ Group, nrow = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    title = "Comparison of Old vs. New Values for Horses, Mules, and Donkeys",
    x = "Type",
    y = "Value"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12)
  )

which generates this plot:

